# Azure Mobile Services C#: how to return full inherited entity and not only the fields of the ancestor

Tags: c#, entity-framework, odata, azure-mobile-services

I have few entities that inherit from a common ancestor.

```
public class Ancestor : EntityData {
 public string AncestorType { get; set; } //kind of enum
}

public class DescendantA : Ancestor {
 public string DescendantAProp { get; set; }
}

public class DescendantB : Ancestor {
 public int DescendantBProp { get; set; }
}
```

I created a controller `AncestorController` to retrieve all the entities in a single call, without the need to replicate the same call several time for `DescendantA`, `DescendantB`, etc.

The controller, scaffolded, looks like this:

```
public class AncestorController : TableController<Ancestor>
{
...

  public IQueryable<Ancestor> GetAllAncestor()
  {
    return Query(); 
  }

...
}
```

Unfortunately the method `GetAllAncestor()` returns only elements with the fields of `Ancestor`, and not the fields of `DescendantA` and/or `DescendantB`.

E.g. example of returned JSON:

```
[
    {
        "deleted": false,
        "updatedAt": "2018-01-23T00:05:52.3Z",
        "createdAt": "2018-01-23T00:05:52.3Z",
        "version": "AAAAAAAAB9Q=",
        "id": "07434aaa-c51a-425a-aca4-90bfb9a06a54",
        "ancestorType": "DescendantA"
    },
    {
        "deleted": false,
        "updatedAt": "2018-01-24T23:00:20.907Z",
        "createdAt": "2018-01-24T23:00:20.692Z",
        "version": "AAAAAAAAJ2U=",
        "id": "08f89ee7-ca78-46ea-9b6a-ef23bda3299b",
        "ancestorType": "DescendantB"
    }
]
```

while I would like to see:

```
[
    {
        "deleted": false,
        "updatedAt": "2018-01-23T00:05:52.3Z",
        "createdAt": "2018-01-23T00:05:52.3Z",
        "version": "AAAAAAAAB9Q=",
        "id": "07434aaa-c51a-425a-aca4-90bfb9a06a54",
        "ancestorType": "DescendantA",
        "DescendantAProp": "SomeValueA"
    },
    {
        "deleted": false,
        "updatedAt": "2018-01-24T23:00:20.907Z",
        "createdAt": "2018-01-24T23:00:20.692Z",
        "version": "AAAAAAAAJ2U=",
        "id": "08f89ee7-ca78-46ea-9b6a-ef23bda3299b",
        "ancestorType": "DescendantB",
        "DescendantBProp": "SomeValueB"
    }
]
```

What should I do to achieve such a goal?

Thanks!!!

cghersi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use view from SQL which gives you this Result

Create View Combine
AS
BEGIN
Select * from DescendantB UNION Select * from DescendantA 
END

and Then in the Table Controller use View instead  of table

```
public class CombineController : TableController<Combine>
{
 ...

  public IQueryable<Combine> GetAllAncestor()
  {
return Query(); 
 }

... 
 }
```

Comment: Thanks! That works for the GET methods. How can I apply this approach to POST/PATCH/DELETE?

Comment: which tables you want to post to? i guess you will need to write custom api's to post data. for post methods, azure mobile sdk will only work one 1->1 mapping and not for complex or multiple table types.

Comment: Thanks @mandar-jogalekar, that is the information I needed, even though unfortunate ;)

Answer (score 0):

> public class AncestorController : TableController

According to the TableController `AncestorController` you defined and the result returned by `GetAllAncestor` method, I assumed that you defined the following DbSet under your `MobileServiceContext` DbContext:

```
public DbSet<Ancestor> Ancestors { get; set; }
```

Based on your code, you defined a SQL database table named `Ancestors`, and it only contains the system columns that come from the `EntityData` and the `AncestorType` column you defined.

> I created a controller AncestorController to retrieve all the entities in a single call, without the need to replicate the same call several time for DescendantA, DescendantB, etc.

Per my understanding, **DescendantA** and **DescendantB** represent as each database table, you need to define your TableController independently and send requests against each table endpoint for retrieving the records.

```
public class DescendantAController : TableController<DescendantA>
{
   //TODO:
}

public class DescendantBController : TableController<DescendantB>
{
   //TODO:
}
```

Moreover, you could also create a new action or override the existing build-in actions provided by TableController and combine all the Descendant table records in a single action, but you may could not leverage some features (e.g. Offline sync,OData query,etc).

Comment: "you need to define your TableController independently and send requests against each table endpoint for retrieving the records." that is exactly what I want to avoid :)

Comment: I have mentioned that you could union items cross different tables. If you still want to use the features provided by `TableController`, I assume that you need to reconsider your design. Do you think just providing a single TableController and handle the CRUD operations against multiple tables make sense?

Comment: Hi Bruce, thanks for the update. The CUD operations whill not work against multiple tables, since they involve a single entity, and such entity is of a defined (sub)type. The only operation that spans across several entities is the query, and mainly this is useful when you want to apply OData filters on your domain. Anyway, given the answer of @mandar-jogalekar, I need to find another way to structure it, until Azure will not provide a native way to handle this.